# Snakemake best practice for demultiplexing

Tags: snakemake

I have a question about best practices. Specifically, about the best snakemake pattern for demultiplexing reads from illumina sequencing. Our workflow needs to demultiplex multiple lanes of sequencing, and then combine these in a single analysis. Obviously, we know lane and sample names, however sample names are not the same across lanes. With only one lane, one can do something like:

```
SAMPLES = [...]
rule demux:
    input:
        reads="lanes/lanename.fastq.gz",
        key="keys/lanename.txt"
    output:
        reads=expand("reads/{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES)
    ...
```

However with multiple lanes, I'm stuck wanting to use a function as an output rule. How would the following translate to something possible:

```
LANES = {
    "lane1": ["S1", "S2"],
    "lane2": ["S3", "S4"],
    "lane3": ["S5", "S6"],
}

rule demux:
    input:
        reads="lanes/{lane}.fastq.gz",
        key="keys/{lane}.txt"
    output:
        reads=lambda wc: expand("reads/{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=LANES[wc.lane])
...
```

Forgive me if this has be answered previously, or if there is some obvious approach I'm missing.

Cheers,
Kevin

Comment: With Snakemake, you have to think the other way round. You need a function or datastructure that provides the lanes for a given sample name.

Comment: @JohannesKöster OK, but then the demultiplexing rule would happen once per sample, right? Because in the DAG, the way of making one sample is to demultiplex them all, and each sample must be created. If the output was something like "reads/{sample}.fastq.gz", without indicating that the rule creates ALL samples for a lane with each run.

Comment: I see, sorry, I misunderstood you. So, you have 1 fastq generating N fastqs. Do you know the sample names beforehand?

Comment: Yes, I know them for each lane (see `LANES` above), but need a general rule for any lane. The rule I describe above is the closest description of what I need, i.e. to be able to define outputs based on wildcards.

Comment: (a) You can have a rule that just extracts a single sample per job. But you have to decide if that would be too much of a bottleneck. (B) You could use dynamic output files. (C) you can generate one rule per lane via a for loop. I would prefer (a). In case of a bottleneck, I'd use (C).

Comment: My current hack is (B), however I hadn't thought of (C). (A) would be far too slow, we can have 1000 samples per lane, and demultiplexing is not exactly instant :).

Comment: What are the chances of the "ideal" rule in my question becoming valid in snakemake (i.e. allow functions in output files). I assume this would interfere with how the DAG is created?

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but I had the same problem, and came up with the following solution: Split the demux rule into two. The first creates a temporary directory which holds the demultiplexed reads, and then the second moves a single readset from that directory.

Here's a relatively minimal example:

```
LANES = {
    "lane1": ["S1", "S2"],
    "lane2": ["S3", "S4"],
    "lane3": ["S5", "S6"],
}

SAMPLES = {}
for lane, samples in LANES.items():
    for sample in samples:
        SAMPLES[sample] = lane


rule all:
    input:
        expand("reads/{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES.keys())


rule get_reads:
    output:
        reads="lanes/{lane}.fastq.gz",
        key="keys/{lane}.txt",
    shell:
        "touch {output}"


rule demux:
    input:
        reads="lanes/{lane}.fastq.gz",
        key="keys/{lane}.txt",
    output:
        directory(temp("demux_tmp_{lane}"))
    params:
        f=lambda w: expand("{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=LANES[w.lane]),
    shell:
        "mkdir -p {output} ; cd {output} ; touch {params.f}"


rule demux_files:
    input:
        lambda w: f"demux_tmp_{SAMPLES[w.sample]}",
    output:
        "reads/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    shell:
        "mv {input}/{wildcards.sample}.fastq.gz {output}"
```